# Rename All files in a Folder and replace the name with the creationTime Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rename

I want to write a function which replace the name of each file with the current name followed by the creatiomTime.
This is my function :

```
Function RenameFolderFiles{
Param([String]$path)
Get-Childitem $path -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace "$_.Name$_.CreationTim" }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: CreationTim or CreationTime - typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice multiple problems. The most important is the fact that your newname-value is `{ $_.Name -Replace "$_.Name$_.CreationTim" }` . The syntax for `-replace` is `-replace 'PatternToReplace', 'NewValue'`. If only pattern is defined, like `-replace 'PatternToReplace'`, then the matched text will be removed.

Lets say a filename is currently "File1.txt". This will never match your `$_.Name$_.CreationTime`-pattern, ex. "File1.txt23.01.2015 23.15.59", so it will never replace/modify the name, and the result will be that your files are renamed to their current name.

Also:

1. `CreationTim` is missing an `e`
2. In `"$_.Name$_.CreationTim"`, you're accessing properties. To include the value of a property inside a string, you need to use subexpresisons `$()` like `"$($_.Name)$($_.CreationTime)"`, or the format operator, like `"{0}{1}" -f $_.Name, $_.CreationTime`
3. You use `-Recurse`, which means you expect subfolders. Folders will also be renamed, which could cause errors later when the path for a file no longer exists (parentfolder is renamed).
4. The `Name`-property includes the extension, so if you had used the `-replace` command right, then "File1.txt" would have become "File1.txt23.01.2015 23.15.59". A file without an extension. To get the filename and extension separately, use the `BaseName`- and `Extension`-properties

I think this is what you're looking for is:

```
Function RenameFolderFiles{
    Param([String]$path)

    Get-Childitem $path -Recurse |
    #Get files only
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
    Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}{2}" -f $_.BaseName, $_.CreationTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy-hhmmss'), $_.Extension }
}
```

Demo:

```
#Files before
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Users\Frode\Desktop" | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\New Text Document - Copy (2).txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\New Text Document - Copy.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\New Text Document.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test\asd - Copy.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test\asd.txt

#Create and run function
Function RenameFolderFiles{
    Param([String]$path)

    Get-Childitem $path -Recurse |
    #Get files only
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
    Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}{2}" -f $_.BaseName, $_.CreationTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy-hhmmss'), $_.Extension }
}

RenameFolderFiles -path "C:\Users\Frode\Desktop"

#Files after
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Users\Frode\Desktop" | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\New Text Document - Copy (2)01022015-122544.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\New Text Document - Copy01022015-122543.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\New Text Document01022015-121535.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test\asd - Copy01022015-122532.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test\asd01022015-122531.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the aanswer, In fact when I execute it I get this error :

`Rename-Item : Impossible de renommer la cible spécifiée, car elle représente un chemin d’accès ou un nom d’appareil.
Au caractère Ligne:5 : 5
+     Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}{2}" -f $_.BaseName, $_.CreationTime, $_.Exten ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
 `

Comment: The script works. The error you are getting is because the new filename is interpeted as a full path. Does your filename contain any special characters?. If not, then I'm guessing that your region settings are returning `CreationTime` as something like `01\02\2015 ... `. You need to specify a format for the datetime. You didn't specify one, so I used the default format for my regional settings. Try updated answer.

Comment: Yeah you are right, because when I execute this command `Get-ChildItem | select-object Creationtime` I get the `mm/dd/yyyy` format. I am trying to fix it ...

Comment: This is it : 

`Function RenameFolderFiles{
    Param([String]$path)
     
    Get-Childitem $path -Recurse |
    #Get files only
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }  |
    Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}{2}" -f $_.BaseName, $_.CreationTime.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy") , $_.Extension }
}
RenameFolderFiles -path "D:\Music\Lessons"  `